# truncate paragraph in each div

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in html, and I want to set all character in every paragraph just 30 chars. My idea is truncate it, but I face a problem how to truncate all paragraph.

This my code

```
<div class="" id="my-gallery-container">
        <div class="item h200" data-order="31">

            <div class="img-85">
                <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">

                <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum
                    et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
                </P>    
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item h200" data-order="30">
            <div class="img-85">
                <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">

                <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum
                    et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
                </P>    
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="item h200" data-order="29">
            <div class="img-85">
                <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">

                <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum
                    et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
                </P>    
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="item h200" data-order="28">
            <div class="img-85">
                <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">

                <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum
                    et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
                </P>    
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this is my script under that code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function truncateText(selector, maxLength) 
    {
        var element = document.querySelector(selector),
            truncated = element.innerText;

        if (truncated.length > maxLength) 
        {
            truncated = truncated.substr(0,maxLength) + '...';
        }
        return truncated;
    };

    document.querySelector('p').innerText = truncateText('p', 30);


</script>
```

but it works only the first paragraph `<p>` , how to truncate all `<p>`? anyone can help me?
Thank you

I hope I didn't repost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
function truncateText(selector, maxLength) {
    // Get all the paragraphs on page
    var paras = document.getElementsByTagName(selector);

    // Loop over paragraphs
    for (var i = 0; i < paras.length; i++) {
        // Get the text of each paragraph element
        var text = paras[i].innerText;

        // Use javascripts substring to trim it and 
        // set it back as the text of the paragraph element
        paras[i].innerText = text.substring(0,maxLength)
    }
}

// Input the p tag
truncateText('p', 30)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t68gue8g/2/
If this is what you want, press the green tick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text to truncate based on the layout, you can do so using CSS `text-overflow`.

This will add an ellipsis after the truncated text:

```css
.parg {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: " Refugium meum et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum "</p>
```

For browser support you can look [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-overflow).